# how do you add code from a text file to a module at runtime in vb

Tags: vb6

i am wanting to add code from a text file at runtime, into a module in visual basic. The reason for this is as my program runs, 'it' may discover a new 'if/then' block or something like that, that it needs to add to its code for future use. So i was going to write the new code to a text file at runtime, save it, then copy it into a module for future use. is there a way to do this? I have been looking on the internet for days with no luck. thanks ahead

Comment: No, that will never work. If there is new code to add then you will need to update and re-compile the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. VB6 compiles files into programs. It can use MSScript.ocx to run VBScript code.

```
 set ScriptControl1 = wscript.createObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl",SC) 
      With ScriptControl1 
         .Language = "VBScript" 
         .UseSafeSubset = False 
         .AllowUI = True 
   .AddCode Script
```

Where script contains the code.

See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d0b64227-f0fd-4cb4-90b7-037bfe95a4ca/how-to-convert-a-vbs-file-to-exe-file?forum=ITCG

For debugging script info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/winscript/active-script-debugging-overview